# Passing .txt files by reference to other functions

Tags: c++

I've got the following code, which simple reads a .txt file for the first two lines, which are supposed to indicate the height and width of a grid that the .txt file carries.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void test(string filename, int& height, int& width);

int main(){
    string filename;
    ifstream infile;
    int height;
    int width;
    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    cin >> filename;
    test(filename, height, width);

    return 0;
}

void test(string filename,int& height, int& width){
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(filename);
    infile >> height;
    infile >> width;
}
```

what I'd like to know if I can change the arguments of `test()` so that it will take the file as an argument, rather than the filename, as I might have to use `.open(filename` elsewhere in other functions, and I don't want to have to keep typing it over and over again. If possible, and I know it is, I would just like to open the file once in main, and be able to use as arguments in any of my files.

Comment: `void test(ifstream& file, int& height, int& width);`

Comment: `std::pair<int, int> read(std::ifstream& file)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass the file to the function.
You have to pass it by reference.

```
void test(std::ifstream& infile, int& height, int& width) {
    infile >> height;
    infile >> width;
}

int main()
{
    std::string filename;

    std::cout << "Enter filename: ";
    std::cin >> filename;

    std::ifstream infile;
    int height;
    int width;
    infile.open(filename);
    test(infile, height, width);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit.

Comment: You've declared the function to take an `ifstream`, but you're still passing the filename.

Comment: He is not passing the filename, he is passing an ifstream variable by reference. Ifstreams are the way c++ handles file input, so in actuality that's the file.

Comment: Don't forget to close the `infile` before _return_ call in main. Use this: `infile.close()`

Comment: I have a question, maybe it isnt related to this question, but if I cout height and width variables in main, they return a garbage value, not the actual height and width that was in the file. Am I passing by reference wrong? I thought that they would be changed.

Comment: @DavidSacco: There is no check to verify that the file has been successfully opened, if error occurs, `height` and `width` have undefined values.

Comment: derp, i was forgetting a `infile.open(filename)` before test. Thank everyone!